Unable to export test run result with GitHub Actions
My goal is to use GHA to export JSON with APEX Test Coverage and sent it to SonarQube for calculation.
I have set up one workflow, that initiates Test Run using SF CLI and now I am writing another workflow to download JSON with this run results.
CLI command I use to get Test Results looks like this:
sf apex get test --test-run-id ${{ secrets.LATEST_TEST_RUN_ID }} --target-org MYORG --output-dir ~/test-result

Despite the fact, that command works on my machine, with Ubuntu build provided by GHA workflow breaks while trying to display test result in output window and further steps are not executed.
We have 450 test methods setup currently.
Is there a way to force GHA to not prompt this test results, if this would help in completing full workflow? Or is there simpler method to what I am trying to achieve here.
This is summary of test run outcome I am trying to export:
=== Test Summary
NAME                 VALUE
───────────────────  ──────────────────────────────────
Outcome              Failed
Tests Ran            449
Pass Rate            98%
Fail Rate            2%
Skip Rate            0%
Test Run Id          ***
Test Execution Time  397279 ms
Org Id               00D7Y0000005LWfUAM
Username             ***
Thanks
Bartek
